# What are the selectors for the GNOME system menu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, themes, css

I'm doing a deep customization of GNOME on my computer and while editing the configs and CSS files for the GNOME shell, I was wondering if there were selectors for the quick menu in GNOME (or a config somewhere that I need to edit).
[image]

Thanks!